# UITableView within UITableViewCell. Unable to detect touch on inner UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer, touches

I have a UITableView on ViewController, which in turn has a UITableView on it's cell. Inner tableView cell has a label, on which I want to detect a gesture or a tap.

I've tried adding gesture to the label but the touches on inner cell isn't getting detected. The didSelectCell delegate method on the inner cell isn't getting detected either.

[image: Trying get touches on a label.]

How can I detect the touch on label?

Datasource and delegates are set from storyboard.

[Find files here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8VpN6IqDj82Rm1rOW5WZG1vSzQ?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share your code? How you generate the cell and the tap gesture?

Comment: did you set datasource and delegate both for inner tableview

Comment: I did yes, the dataSource is populating the cell. But when I try to receive tap gesture the only tap registered in on the outer tableView's cell.

Comment: Do you enable user interaction in the label? it is disabled by default

Comment: @LucasPalaian Set have set it as enabled.

Comment: @LucasPalaian I have added a link to the files, please see.